# Multiple call to async_accept

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Is it OK to call [async_accept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept.html) again before handler of the previous call is invoked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of async_accept:

> Regardless of whether the asynchronous operation completes immediately
>   or not, the handler will not be invoked from within this function.
>   Invocation of the handler will be performed in a manner equivalent to
>   using boost::asio::io_service::post().

The io_service has a queue of callbacks that will be processed independently of what happens in async_accept. So, yes, you can call it multiple times, and each time it will queue up your call to the handler, and the io_service will pull them off the queue and execute your handler.